# getServerSideProps query variable type "string[]" is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: typescript, next.js, server-side-rendering

I get the above Error inside my async `getServerSideProps` after I do `parseInt` the incoming value of my query variable (example: `/items?page=1`). I need to convert the value into a number so I can later increase or decrease when navigating other pages views.

This is the code I do have: All in Nextjs SSR:

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  // API endpoint fetch
  // request data : array of 7 items & page you are
  const page: number = context.query.page ? parseInt(context.query?.page) : 0 // Page we want to access
  const props = { page }
  return {
    props,
  }
}
```

Comment: This is how I'm handling it (although it's not perfect): https://stackoverflow.com/q/71273690/470749