# How to use query params in Next.js?

Tags: node.js, next.js, query-string

In my Next.js API functions like:

```
export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse<any>) {
  const { someQueryParam } = req.query;
  doSomething(someQueryParam);
  ...
```

I see TypeScript error:

> Argument of type 'string | string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
> Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)

So I've started using this helper function I wrote:

```
export function getSimpleStringFromParam(paramValue: string | string[] | undefined) {
  if (paramValue) {
    return typeof paramValue === 'string' ? paramValue : paramValue[0];
  } else {
    return '';
  }
}
```

It works fine, but it feels ugly and weird and feels like what I'm trying to do would be such a common need that Next.js or Node would handle it more smoothly. So I feel like I'm misunderstanding something.

Is there a more official / better way to pluck simple string values out of the query params?

Comment: I always just dangerously assume its a string or undefined by casting it as string... and then have a falsey check before I use it... +1 for asking a question I should have asked months ago.

Comment: You're not misunderstanding it, that's exactly what should be done. Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60110364/type-string-string-is-not-assignable-to-type-string.

Comment: @juliomalves Thanks. I wonder if casting to a string like https://stackoverflow.com/a/70530902/470749 is a better approach than mine. Feels cleaner (if it works).

Comment: It's not as safe as adding the type check like you do, and would cause a runtime error if the query param is an array. When casting you're simply making TypeScript happy, not preventing the error from happening.

Answer (score 0):

I look at your helper function and see that `someQueryParam` is string

```
export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse<any>) {
  const someQueryParam: string = req.query.someQueryParam
    ? req.query.someQueryParam as string
    : "";
  doSomething(someQueryParam);
}
```

But if you need get `string | string[]` use that:

```
export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse<any>) {
  const someQueryParam: string | string[] = req.query.someQueryParam
    ? req.query.someQueryParam
    : "";
  doSomething(someQueryParam);
}
```

OR

```
 export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse<any>) {
  const { someQueryParam } = req.query.someQueryParam
    ? req.query
    : { someQueryParam: "" };
  doSomething(someQueryParam);
}
```